# Add wired lan adapter to Windows 7 on a Lenovo X200?

Tags: windows-7, lan, wired

I am using a Lenovo x200. By default it has a wireless connection. However, when I try to use a wired Lan in some places, I cannot find the local area connection adapter.

How do I add this?

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel (icon view) > Network and sharing Center > Set Up A New Connection Or Network.

.

Comment: I tried. But still don't work.

Anymore detail please?

Comment: Lenovo probably has some sort of network management software installed, this may be the problem, unfortunately I don't know much about the software.